# Can a webservice be called from the .Net 4 Client Profile?

Tags: .net-client-profile

Is there a way to call a webservice from a .Net 4 Client Profile client?  My understanding is that System.Web is not available in the Client Profile 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Web.Services is available in the client profile. It was split apart from System.Web for .NET 4 just for this very scenario.